# Jpanel is not opening but without any error in java swing

Tags: java, swing

I can't open below panel even not showing any exception.below code for creating Jpanel. I am calling this object from another class that is also not working. note that not showing any error while running application.application simply terminated after executing last line.

```
public SplitRequestView(){

    try {
        System.out.println("Split vioew Called");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(0,0));
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        JPanel rootPanel = new JPanel();
        rootPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        add(rootPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        rootPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        final JPanel headerPanel = new JPanel();
        rootPanel.add(headerPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        headerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10, 60));
        headerPanel.setBorder(null);
        headerPanel.setBackground(Constants.searchBackgroundColor);
        headerPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("","10[][][grow]20","10[]10[]10"));

        JLabel lbl_title_split = new FinaWindowTitleLabel("Split");
        headerPanel.add(lbl_title_split, "cell 0 0,growx");

        JLabel lbl_title_product = new FinaWindowTitleLabel("Product Details");
        headerPanel.add(lbl_title_product, "cell 0 1,growx");

        rootPanel.add(headerPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);

        final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
        contentPanel.setBorder(null);
        contentPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        rootPanel.add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel panelProdcutDetails = new JPanel();
        panelProdcutDetails.setBorder(null);
        panelProdcutDetails.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(445,50));
        panelProdcutDetails.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panelProdcutDetails.setLayout(new MigLayout("","10[35]5[35]5[35]5[35]5[35]5[35]5[35]5[35]10","10[]5[]5[]10"));
        contentPanel.add(panelProdcutDetails,BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JLabel lbl_pcode = new FinaLabelStyle("Product Code");
        panelProdcutDetails.add(lbl_pcode,"cell 0 0,growx");

        JLabel lbl_pcode_value = new FinaLabelStyle("P01");
        panelProdcutDetails.add(lbl_pcode_value,"cell 0 1,growx");

        JLabel lbl_pname = new FinaLabelStyle("Product Name");
        panelProdcutDetails.add(lbl_pname,"cell 1 0,growx");

        JLabel lbl_pname_value = new FinaLabelStyle("Sample Produt");
        panelProdcutDetails.add(lbl_pname_value,"cell 1 1,growx");

        JLabel lbl_internalbatch = new FinaLabelStyle("Internal Batch Id");
        panelProdcutDetails.add(lbl_internalbatch,"cell 2 0,growx");

        JLabel lbl_internalbatch_value = new FinaLabelStyle("P22");
        panelProdcutDetails.add(lbl_internalbatch_value,"cell 2 1,growx");

        JLabel lbl_supplierbatch = new FinaLabelStyle("Supplier Batch Id");
        panelProdcutDetails.add(lbl_supplierbatch,"cell 3 0,growx");

        JLabel lbl_supplierbatch_value = new FinaLabelStyle("P2202");
        panelProdcutDetails.add(lbl_supplierbatch_value,"cell 3 1,growx");

        JLabel lbl_uom = new FinaLabelStyle("UOM");
        panelProdcutDetails.add(lbl_uom,"cell 4 0,growx");

        JLabel lbl_uom_value = new FinaLabelStyle("10kg");
        panelProdcutDetails.add(lbl_uom_value,"cell 4 1,growx");

        JLabel lbl_currentstock = new FinaLabelStyle("Current Stock");
        panelProdcutDetails.add(lbl_currentstock,"cell 5 0,growx");

        JLabel lbl_currentstock_value = new FinaLabelStyle("10kg");
        panelProdcutDetails.add(lbl_currentstock_value,"cell 5 1,growx");

        JPanel panelSplit = new JPanel();
        panelSplit.setBorder(null);
        panelSplit.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(445,70));
        panelSplit.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panelSplit.setLayout(new MigLayout("","10[35]5[35]5[35]5[35]5[35]5[35]10","10[]5[]5[]10"));
        contentPanel.add(panelSplit,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JLabel lbl_title = new FinaWindowTitleLabel("Split UOM");
        panelSplit.add(lbl_title,"cell 0 0,growx");

        JLabel lbl_qtytitle = new FinaLabelStyle("Quantity to be Converted");
        panelSplit.add(lbl_qtytitle,"cell 0 1,growx");

        JTextField txtQtytobeconverted = new FinaNewTextField();
        txtQtytobeconverted.setDocument(new JTextFieldLimit(30));
        txtQtytobeconverted.setColumns(12); 
        panelSplit.add(txtQtytobeconverted,"cell 0 2,growx");

        JLabel lbl_convertuom = new FinaLabelStyle("Convert UOM");
        panelSplit.add(lbl_convertuom,"cell 1 1");

        JLabel lbl_convertuom_value = new FinaLabelStyle("Convert UOM Value");
        panelSplit.add(lbl_convertuom_value,"cell 1 2");

        JLabel lbl_to = new FinaLabelStyle("To");
        panelSplit.add(lbl_to,"cell 2 1");

        JLabel lbl_to_image = new FinaLabelStyle("to");
        panelSplit.add(lbl_to_image,"cell 2 2");

        JLabel lbl_target_uom = new FinaLabelStyle("Target UOM");
        panelSplit.add(lbl_target_uom,"cell 3 1");

        JComboBox<String> cmbBaseUOM = new FinaCustomComboBox();
        panelSplit.add(cmbBaseUOM,"cell 3 2");

        JLabel lbl_qty = new FinaLabelStyle("Qty");
        panelSplit.add(lbl_qty,"cell 4 1,growx");

        JTextField txtQty = new FinaNewTextField();
        txtQty.setDocument(new JTextFieldLimit(30));
        txtQty.setColumns(12); 
        panelSplit.add(txtQty,"cell 4 2,growx");

        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            log.error("Error in Opening Split Window : "+ex.getMessage());
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SplitRequestView requestView = new SplitRequestView();
        requestView.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: might it be because you never call setVisible on the frame?

Comment: i am setting through the object creation in main method.

Comment: based on the code you've shared, we can't see if that class is a JFrame, and/or if that is what should be checked

Comment: this class extends jpanel()

Comment: ... add your JPanel to a JFrame, and set that to visible

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: As indicated the top level root component is a `JFrame` (a window, and some variants like JDialog). If you want a JFrame without window frame, call JFrame.`setUndecorated(true)`.